# new regex rule for meio mask

Tags: jquery, masking, meiomask

I'm using [meio mask](https://github.com/fabiomcosta/jquery-meiomask) ([old site](https://web.archive.org/web/20110705060327/http://meiocodigo.com/projects/meiomask))

I want to be able to mask an input so it allows me to enter a percentage value between 0 and 100, integers only.

I've tried this:

```
$.mask.rules = $.extend($.mask.rules, {
    '%': /0|[1-9][0-9]?|100/,
});

$.mask.masks = $.extend($.mask.masks, {
    "percentage": { mask: "%%%" }
});
```

But it doesn't work. How can I write a proper rule to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

The following code should do the trick, the rule matches any number between 0 and 100, including leading zeros. The ? in [1-9]?[0-9] allows for single-digit numbers (e.g., "5") and double-digit numbers (e.g., "23"), but not triple-digit numbers (e.g., "105"). The | separates the two possible matches for 100.

```
$.mask.rules = $.extend($.mask.rules, {
    '%': /[1-9]?[0-9]|100/
});
```

This sets the mask to "###%", which allows up to three digits followed by a percent symbol. The rules option specifies the % rule we defined earlier, so it will only allow valid percentage values.

```
$.mask.masks = $.extend($.mask.masks, {
    "percentage": { mask: "###%", rules: { '%': /[1-9]?[0-9]|100/ } }
});
```

Comment: I can't write anything on my input